# Parallel execution of c++ code built with VS2017

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, parallel-processing

I have noticed that running a code built with Visual Studio 2017, almost all the cores of my pc are used. I find it strange because for what I know I didn't give any directive for a multithreaded/parallel compilation of my code. 
Can you explain me why this is happening?

Comment: How are you launching the application? From inside VS? If so, the IDE itself will use several threads. How are you determining the threads are from your application and not the OS or other applications instead?

Comment: Ken, you were right, I deeply analysed the execution and it is just using one processor per time,even if it looks like it is jumping from one core to anther and this made me thinking it was executing the program in parallel.